# Remove a tag from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to remove a single tag from the DOM using jQuery or JavaScript. I only need to remove the enclosing tag, *not* the content inside the tag.

`remove()`, `detach()`,  `empty()` methods cannot be applied as they remove the whole content as well.

for example:

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

need to remove only the `<table></table>`.

Currently DOM looks like this

```
<table style="width:600px">
<tbody><p> Number  -  Name  -   <br></p>
    <p> 111  -  ABC  -  <br></p>
    <p> 222  -  KLM  -  <br></p>
    <p> 333  -  NOP  - <br></p>
    <p> 444  -  HIJ  -  <br></p>
</tbody></table>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you removed the table element and left the table row elements behind then the document would be invalid. Why would you want that?

Comment: I agree with @Quentin. You shouldn't do it, but for this specific example, you could do something like `var table = document.querySelector("table"); table.outerHTML = table.innerHTML;`

Comment: No all these table data needs to be represented in paragraphs. Now I get the paragraphs inside a cage. I want to remove that. for that I need to remove the table tag as well. <th> <td> all are removed in the DOM.

Comment: What does the HTML look like now and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: @user3547920 if you're counting on the `<tr>` and `<td>` being removed as well, how about using the .text() method to extract the text and then replace in a paragraph? Is that the intent? It would be useful if you included what your desired resulting DOM would be.

Comment: I included what the DOM looks currently. I need to remove the <table> tag. There are lot of other tables as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try to `.unwrap()` it, but the result would be an invalid html,

```
$('tr').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text=$("table").text();
$("table").parent().html(text);// now at the place of text come
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table").replaceWith($("table").html());
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery :

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```